# Particularization rules of premises with multiple quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have this reasoning with multiple quantifiers and I need to prove it's validity

$\exists x : [F(x) \wedge S(x)] \rightarrow \forall y : [M(y) \rightarrow W(y)]$

$\exists y : [M(y) \wedge \neg W(y)]$

∴ $\forall x : [F(x) \rightarrow \neg S(x)] $

My question is if I can particularize the quantifiers of the first premise separately, since the variables are different for each one. If not, then what's the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment*

Details depend on the proof system used... but to "can I particularize the quantifiers of the first premise separately?" the answer is NO.

What we can do is to use [Prenex Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) and re-write the 1st premise in the equivalent form:

> $∀x[(F(x)∧S(x)) → ∀y (M(y)→W(y))].$

Having said that, a proof strategy can be:

Assume $Fa$ and assume $Sa$ and thus derive $Fa \land Sa$ and then $\exists x (Fx \land Sx)$.

With it, form 1st premise, derive $\forall y (My \to Wy)$ and using Existential Elimination on the 2nd premise derive a contradiction, from which you can close the sub-proof of EE and derive $\lnot Sa$ and finally $Fa \to \lnot Sa$, without open assumptions left and thus you can generalize it.